# Jmeter Async process with while controller

Tags: asynchronous, jmeter

In order to verify whether my concurrency request is persisted asynchronously in the datastore. I have the below test plan which makes requests to the database as part of the preprocessor in the while controller. is this the right test plan? I am not able to see the preprocessor running in the while controller. the logs are not displaying.

sample preprocessor is below

````
MFG mfgRepo = new MFG();
log.info("device {}","${deviceID}");
long crashTime= Long.parseLong(vars.get('p1'));
String deviceId1=vars.get('deviceID');
log.info("the crashtime is {}",crashTime);

List<Map<String,Object>> dbItem = mfgRepo.getItemFromDB("TEST",deviceId1,crashTime);
String info=dbItem.get(0).get("info"); ```
 
how to validate in while controller the data is persisted in the database?
````

Comment: preprocessor won't be executed without any sampler inside scope (while controller)

Comment: how can  I  run the while controller to run the above process.

Answer (score 0):

PreProcessor itself will not be executed, you need to have a [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) inside the While Controller in order to enter the While Loop and/or execute the pre/post processors, assertions and timers so:

1. Either switch to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) instead of the JSR223 PreProcessor
2. Or add a [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler as a child of the While Controller, this guy doesn't generate a sample result so you won't see it in the [Listeners](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-listeners-part-3-listeners-calculate-distribution-metrics/) or in the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles), however it will trigger the execution of the PreProcessor.

Comment: I added dummy sampler to achieve and tried flow control it worked but how can I make this call asynchronously. so that I can continue sending the requests to the system